# I'm trying to fetch unique values from one column (registration_no) which has duplicate values in column(mobileno) and column(email)

Tags: mysql

This is my table - I want to get the **unique registration_no's** which have same mobileno, email and date_of_action. 
For instance row no **8,9** and rows **10,11,12,13**

[image]

Comment: *Note: Would like to add that registration_no, mobileno, email are from COMPLAINT table and action_status, date_of_action are from ACTIONHISTORY table.

Comment: Do not select fields which may differ for the same `registration_no`, and use DISTINCT.

Comment: We would like to help. But we want to see your code and both tables to give a correct answer.